# How can I add a neutral to my subpanel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a 60a subpanel on the side of my house for the pool equipment. There are only two conductors and a ground. Originally the only things that were probably connected were the pool pump and heater, both 240 volts. But the lack of a neutral prevents the extra spaces from being used for 120 volt circuits.

And at some point, that's what happened. There's a 120v receptacle under the panel. Apparently, whoever installed this realized the problem, and at least was smart enough not to use the subpanel grounding conductor as a neutral.

About 20 feet away from the panel, there is another circuit feeding the a/c condenser, which does have a neutral for some reason (its unused by the condenser). So, whoever installed the receptacle ran a single 12 ga conductor (in conduit) from the a/c disconnect to the subpanel and used that for the receptacle's neutral.

Yes, it's infinitely better than using the subpanel's ground conductor as a neutral, but it makes me cringe and I want to add another 120v circuit or two so I want to fix this the right way.

Seems to me I have two choices. One, replace the entire feed to the subpanel with a 4/3 cable, or run a single #4 conductor from the main panel to the subpanel for the neutral.
Since you can't buy single conductor Romex, I assume I'd have to run it in conduit. The second option would be much cheaper, but is it against code or a bad idea for some other reason? Could I run the single #4 conductor in 3/8 flex conduit rather than PVC? It would be entirely in the attic.

Comment: how is the original feed run? in conduit or a romex-alike?

Comment: If your original feed to this 60A panel is in conduit, you can simply pull a new neutral _wire_ to it. If it was fed with a _cable_, not so much... Edit in pics of the panel with the cover off so we can see how it's been fed. With _some_ cables you _might_ be able to repurpose the current "ground" wire as your neutral and add a ground. Again, pics will allow the actual electricians (as opposed to me who plays one at home but is _far_ from licensed) to make a proper assessment.

Comment: Unlike a ground wire, I believe that neutral cannot be separated from the hots.  It must be in the cable or the same conduit.  Romex/NM-B cannot be outside of the house.  Though the wall into the panel is okay, but can't be in conduit outside of the wall.

Comment: The original feed is a jacketed cable. Through the attic and down inside the wall into the back of the panel.

Comment: I really doubt the current ground could be repurposed as a neutral. It would have to be #4 like the other conductors.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what sort of 120 volt circuits are wanted, but.. _that outlet could be properly installed at the A/C disconnect_. This might possibly require replacement of the existing disconnect with a subpanel.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. I installed a salt water chlorine generator and plugged it into that outlet, but it can be reconfigued for 240v, I'd just have to replace the plug and receptacle.

I have a new 12v pool light, not sure if that can be wired for 240v or not. I also bought a CO2 pH injector system. Also not sure if it could be configured for 240v.

I hadn't considered just leaving things alone and just using the existing panel exclusively for 240v loads, and running another circuit or two. Definitely easier and cheaper as far as materials costs go.

Comment: There is also a circuit for the sprinkler pump nearby. I'll have to check wire sizes and measure the loads on the sprinkler pump and a/c condenser to see if there's any excess capacity. If not, probably the simplest solution is to run a 12/3 back to the main panel to feed a few outlets near the pool equipment pad.

Comment: Update, the pool light and chlorine generator can both work on 240v, the pH injector, no. Another possibility is that there's enough capacity in the existing panel for the sprinkler pump, then I repurpose the sprinkler pump wiring for 120v outlets.

Comment: Has the A/C condenser been replaced with a more efficient one over the years, leaving the /3+gnd feeder larger than it needs to be?

Comment: Yes, it was replaced less than a year ago. However, it's a small unit (1.5 ton I think) just for the master bedroom and bath, and it's on a 15 amp breaker in the main panel. I'll have to check the actual wire size, but probably not much extra capacity there. 

I'm leaning towards moving the sprinkler pump over to the pool subpanel and repurposing that circuit. But I need to wait until my new pool heater arrives in a week or two, and then check the total load on the pool subpanel panel (pump & heater & chlorine generator) to see if it can handle the sprinkler pump.

Comment: Here's another concern I have. As I understand it, a heat pump type pool heater is required to be on a GFCI protected circuit. But if there's no neutral in the sub-panel, that precludes the use of GFCI breakers in the sub-panel. Ugh. The cost of new 4/3 to the sub-panel is going to be over $800. Brutal.

I suppose I could replace the 70 amp breaker in the main panel that feeds the sub-panel with a GFCI breaker, or is there some reason I shouldn't do that?